# Paramiko, sftp can not download from linux server to windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, sftp, paramiko

I try to download .zip files from a linux machine to windows machine (local). I am certain that my paths and files are fine since it works perfectly with my Linux machine. So, with windows I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last)

   self.sftp.get(self.fullremotepath, localpath)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 638, in get file_size = self.stat(remotepath).st_size
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 331, in statt, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 649, in _request return self._read_response(num)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 696, in_read_response self._convert_status(msg)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 722, in_convert_status
   raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, text) IOError: [Errno 2] No such file
```

here is my script :

```
class DownloadFiles(object):

    def __init__(self, path, missing):

    '''
    path    : local path to the month directory 
    missing : list of the missing files for a month

    '''

    host = "xxx"                    #hard-coded
    port = 22
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))

    password = "xx"                #hard-coded
    username = "guest"                #hard-coded
    transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

    self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)

    self.roothremotepath = os.path.join(os.sep,'data','project','archive','data')
    self.download(path, missing)

    self.sftp.close()
    transport.close()


def download(self, path, missing):

    for i in missing:
        yearMonth  = os.path.basename(str(path))
        self.fullremotepath = os.path.join(self.roothremotepath, yearMonth, i + '.zip')
        localpath  = os.path.join(str(path), i + '.zip')
        self.sftp.get(self.fullremotepath, localpath)
        self.unzip(localpath)

def unzip(self, zippath):

    with zipfile.ZipFile(zippath, "r") as z:
        z.extractall(zippath.replace('.zip',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is your problem:

```
self.roothremotepath = os.path.join(os.sep,'data','project','archive','data')
```

The return value of `os.sep` depends on your host OS.

Running it on Linux:

```
>>> import os
>>> rootpath = os.path.join(os.sep, 'data', 'project', 'archive', 'data')
>>> print rootpath
/data/project/archive/data
```

Running it on Windows:

```
>>> import os
>>> rootpath = os.path.join(os.sep, 'data', 'project', 'archive', 'data')
>>> print rootpath
\data\project\archive\data
```

You might try hardcoding the UNIX-style path separator `'/'` in the remote path.